# navigation menu with different color using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is my html code. I am trying to make this link different color but using jquery.

```css
nav ul li:nth-child(1) a { color: orange; }
nav ul li:nth-child(2) a { color: red; }
nav ul li:nth-child(3) a { color: green; }
nav ul li:nth-child(4) a { color: brown; }
nav ul li:nth-child(5) a { color: yellow; }
nav ul li:nth-child(6) a { color: purple; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

also active link will be black(#000) color.and active link background will be the link color.

Answer (score 4):

You can store your colors into an array, then using selector get the `li`s and iterate over them. In each iteration use [**jQuery#css**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function to apply the colors using the index of the `li` in the list and index of the color in the `colors`.

But it is better to use `css` to apply styles to the items. Only dynamic changed styles must be applied using jQuery. How many works will be set on the css instead of jQuery, faster it will work.

```js
const colors = [ 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow', 'purple'];

$('nav ul li a').each(function(index, item) {
   $(item).css('color', colors[index]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: you may need to add **a** in your selector

Comment: thank you @ Temani it works good.but when a link will be active..then it's background will be this link-color.and this link color will be black (#000).
is that possible to do that....?
i am working with **bootstrap tabs/pills**  **Toggleable / Dynamic Tabs**

Answer (score 0):

Check this.Tested!!!

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul li a').each(function(index,item) {
       //color = "#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
       //select = "ul > li:nth-child("+i+") > a";
       color  = getRandomColor();
       $(item).css('color',color);
    });

   });

   function getRandomColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
     }
</script>
```